# How to align Gridspace plots in holoviews Layout?

Tags: holoviews, pyviz, hvplot

I have trouble understanding how the holoviews Layout works if it contains Gridspace components. In the example below I have 2 simple plots that are returned as Gridspace. While they display just fine, I'd like to align them on the right edge. According to the docs, that should be done by passing `align='end'` option to the respective component(s) in the Layout - however this will result in `ValueError: Unexpected option 'align' for GridSpace type across all extensions. No similar options found.` error.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.arange(100)
df['y'] = df['x']*10
df['c1'] = [1] * 25 + [2] * 25 + [3] * 25 + [4] * 25
df['c2'] = [1] * 50 + [2] * 50

p1 = df.hvplot(x='x', y='y', datashade=False, row='c1')
p2 = df.hvplot(x='x', y='y', datashade=False, row='c2')
(p1.opts(align='end') + p2).cols(1)
```

This will work fine without the `.opts(align='end)` other than the alignment being on the left: [plot without align](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I604j.png)
It would be great if someone knows whether this is a limitation of Gridspaces or I was just using the wrong options.